# Using multiprocessing in for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, multiprocessing

I have the following for loop that takes 2 arrays, fuzzy matches the value of elements from the first column with the elements from the second column and returns the closest match.
Because the data sets I'm working with are huge, the loop takes forever to run. Is there a way for me to improve the speed of the loop using multiprocessing?

````
    def match(Col1,Col2):
    overall=[]
    for n in Col1:
        result=[(fuzz.token_set_ratio(n, n2),n2) 
                for n2 in Col2 if fuzz.token_set_ratio(n, n2)>20
               ]
        if len(result):
            result.sort()
            #print("CP4")
            #print('result {}'.format(result))
            print("Best Match={}".format(result[-1][1]))
            overall.append(result[-1][1])
        else:
            overall.append(" ")
    return overall ```
````

Answer (score 0):

[multiprocessing.Pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) seems fitting for your use case. If you want different workers to process different elements of `Col1`:

```
def work(n):
    result = []
    for n2 in Col2:
        token_set_ratio = fuzz.token_set_ratio(n, n2)
        if token_set_ratio > 20:
            result.append(token_set_ratio)
    if result:
        best_match = max(result)
        print("Best Match={}".format(best_match))
        return best_match
    else:
        return ' '

num_workers = 8
with multiprocessing.Pool(num_workers) as pool:
    overall = pool.map(work, Col1)
```

Note that I also included two performance optimizations:

1. Calculate `fuzz.token_set_ratio(n, n2)` only once and reuse the result;
2. Take the max of the list `result` instead of sorting it, as you only need the best match. This improves complexity from O(n log(n)) to O(n).

Comment: Thanks so much, @xcmkz. I tried your solution but it gives me an error stating col1 is undeclared. Could you help me with that?

Comment: I assumed `Col1` would be defined as it appeared to be an iterable object in the code in your original question...